# String null when loading food description from firebase Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Actually i am making a food app where you can order foods by choosing category of food and adding them to carts. when i sign in and choose category of food and then choose a food to display description and add it to the cart the app stop working and the problem is in the picture below. 
Here is the picture with the logcat (run) problem https://ibb.co/bJ2Xzw . 
I receive string null and app stop working.
Also am using Firebase
If needed more coding i will post it.
Thank you.

problem from RUN : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference at com.example.onix.androideat.FoodList.onCreate(FoodList.java:49)

Comment: switch the conditions of the && (`if categoryId != null && !categoryId.isEmpty())

Comment: Thank you for answering. I try it and now it shows a blank page hmm.

Comment: In RUN: ''E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout''
picture 1: https://ibb.co/hMVfNG
picture 2: https://ibb.co/f4JBUw

Comment: That's because `categoryId` is null so the problem is with getting the value from the intent. Check if the key is correct

Comment: Oh wait my fault i understanded wrong.. le me check

Comment: Fount it thank you mate appreciate it.Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to debug and find if your getting a data to categoryId.

if you are getting any values, try the code below:

```
if(!categoryId.equals("")){
    loadListFood()
}
```

do not forget to initialize category.

Comment: Thank you a lot but i already fix it :) i just switch conditions of && like ' Omar Al Halabi! said.

Comment: Enjoy coding!! @Onix

Comment: Thanks mate am trying too the problem is that when i load category its blank page.. trying to fix it :)
Have a nice day